# Make div same size as other images

Tags: html, css

I have a website that im working on and there is a box with some links it it. I want this box to be the same size as the images around it. Right now the problem is that when the window size gets smaller the images will scale smaller or larger but this div with these links does not scale the same way.

Here is a image (left box is the links, images are surrounding it):

[image]

Here is html for the download box and images:

```
<div class="appDownload">
                <header class="downloadHeader"><span class="downloadTitle">Download</span></header>
                <!--<a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/igun-pro-hd/id574123647?mt=8">Apple App Store</a></br>
                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avidionmedia.iGunHD">Google Play Store</a></br>
                <a href="http://www.amazon.com/iGun-Pro-Original-Gun-App/dp/B00G4E1DOI">Amazon App Store</a></br> -->
                <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/igun-pro-hd/id574123647?mt=8" target="_blank">
                    <div class="appStoreBadge"><img src="images/App_Store_Badge135x40.svg" width="100%"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avidionmedia.iGunHD" target="_blank">
                    <div class="appStoreBadge"><img 
src="images/Google_Play_Badge564x168.png" width="100%"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="http://www.amazon.com/iGun-Pro-Original-Gun-App/dp/B00G4E1DOI" target="_blank">
                    <div class="appStoreBadge"><img 
src="images/Amazon_Badge564x168.png" width="100%"></div>
                </a>


            </div>
```

The images:

```
 <div class="appScreenshots">

                <img id="screenshot1" width="100%" src="images/igp1_screenshot_1.png">
                <img id="screenshot2" width="100%" src="images/igp1_screenshot_3.png">
                <img id="screenshot2" width="100%" src="images/igp1_screenshot_5.png">
                <img id="screenshot2" width="100%" src="images/igp1_screenshot_7.png">

            </div>
```

This is the download box css:

```
.appDownload{
width: 100%;
margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
background: #333;
float: left;
}
```

And this is the css for the images:

```
.appScreenshots{
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
background: transparent;
overflow: hidden;
}

.appScreenshots img{
float: none;
clear: none;
}
```

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` to  each of them

Comment: To the screenshots or the appbadges? or?

Comment: To each img and that particular div as well.. You cam try `display:table-cell` also.

Comment: cant get it to do anything err